# MySQL / php INSERT Statement Showing Unpredictable Results w/ No Insert

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

All the data is being passed as I have sufficiently tested over and over to ensure it is complete. The problem I am having is with my INSERT statement:

```
<?php
$db_name = "db";
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
$sql = "INSERT INTO badges        (id,company_name,company_address,company_city,company_state,company_zip, badge_name,   badge_title) VALUES ";
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['badge_name']); $i++) {
$sql = "(
$_SESSION[company_name],
$_SESSION[company_address],
$_SESSION[company_city],    
$_SESSION[company_state],
$_SESSION[company_zip],
".$_POST['badge_name'][$i].",
".$_POST['badge_title'][$i].")";}
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
echo print_r($sql);
?>
```

And my $sql print_r() is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Test Company Name, 1224 Adams Ave, Portland,  Oregon, 97128, Bill Smith, W' at line 2
```

No data is being inserted in my table. I have verified and tested user/pass etc. All working OK.

For good measure, here is my array output showing ALL data is passed as expected.

Mike Jones
Owner
Test Company Name
1224 Adams Ave
Portland
Oregon
97128
Bill Smith
Worker
Test Company Name
1224 Adams Ave
Portland
Oregon
97128

I think I am missing something stupid simple here, but just been on this for 4-5 hours starting to go nuts! Thanks for any insight as to my ignorance!

Here is my table dump for any reference:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `badges` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`company_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`company_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`company_city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`company_state` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`company_zip` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
`badge_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`badge_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: i wonder it you ever consider to post whole erroneous query, not a stub of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work, note the sql concat , for multiple inserts

```
    <?php 
function cleanit($input){
    return mysql_real_escape_string(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\?.,_ -]/s', '', $input));
}
        $db_name = "db";
        $connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
        $db = mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
        $sql = "INSERT INTO badges (id,company_name,company_address,company_city,company_state,company_zip, badge_name, badge_title) VALUES ";
        for($i = 0; $i <= count($_POST['badge_name']); $i++) {


        $sql .= '("","'.cleanit($_SESSION['company_name']).'",
        "'.cleanit($_SESSION['company_address']).'",
        "'.cleanit($_SESSION['company_city']).'",    
        "'.cleanit($_SESSION['company_state']).'",
        "'.cleanit($_SESSION['company_zip']).'",
        "'.cleanit($_POST['badge_name'][$i]).'",
        "'.cleanit($_POST['badge_title'][$i]).'")';
        if($i<count($_POST['badge_name'])){$sql .=',';}
     }
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        echo print_r($sql);
        ?>
```

Comment: NO matter the variation I try, I get random mixed results cut short like: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '("","Test Company Name", "1224 Adams Ave", "Portland", "Orego' at line 7

Comment: You will note the state is cut short, and the badge_name and title are missing!

Comment: @Lawrence, well the data is now inserting : ), but there is a 3rd blank record being added every time. And there is an offset MySQL error being thrown upon submission.. At least I am not hyper-ventilating any more! Onto something but more to solve : (

Comment: must be because you have a blank entry in the $_POST['badge_name'] var somewhere, do a check with echo'<pre>'; print_r($_POST);echo'</pre>';

Comment: put the sqlquery below the print_r statement, your get an output then :)

Comment: i think this ornate regexp is redundant. some characters you're stripping off with it are quite useful. quotes for example. however, your answer is the best so far

Comment: thx i normally strip everything except 0-9a-zA-Z, but was trying tobe quick lol

Comment: Yeah this answer was the one that made sense observing the missing new record ,. I'm just stuck now not being able to get rid of this blank record being inserted. Did a dump, and guessing it might be the submit button: Array
(
    [badge_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jason Edward
            [1] => Tkeisha Michaels
        )

    [badge_title] => Array
        (
            [0] => Programmer
            [1] => Phones
        )

    [continue_2] => Submit Badges >>
)

Comment: I tried array_pop to remove that last element but could not get it to kick

Comment: just remove it from the html form <input type="submit" value="Submit Badges" name="continue_2"> to <input type="submit" value="Submit Badges"> you can use <input type="hidden" name="continue_2" value="1"> if the next page requires it, note: you should always pass form values through php before adding to the db or building an array as someone could make there own form with some sql injection, ya should never just loop through a POST to build a query its also good practice to use the isset() function on all vars before setting

Comment: Weird. Remove the html and its still adding the blank record. Only the company info is being carried through the the added record. Got to be a looping issue or something... Hmmmm

Comment: Lawrence, I solved the final issue by a suggestion from Gaurav. My updated query looks like this: for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['badge_name']); $i++) 
{
  $sql .= "('"
   . $_SESSION['company_name'] . "','"
            . $_SESSION['company_address'] . "','"
            . $_SESSION['company_city'] . "','"
            . $_SESSION['company_state'] . "','"
            . $_SESSION['company_zip'] . "','"
            . $_POST['badge_name'][$i] . "','"
            . $_POST['badge_title'][$i] ."')";

  if($i<count($_POST['badge_name'])-1){$sql .=',';} (note the -1)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is not enclosing your strings upon insert

```
$_SESSION[company_name]
```

to

```
'$_SESSION[company_name]'
```

same goes for others, your string is not treated as a string but an sql sort of token

Comment: do you keep mysql query logs? if so. post the raw mysql query that is being produced here. That will help you/me solving your error.

Comment: @OldWest you should not "try" it, silly. You have to **always follow SQL rules**, not trying it just in case. If you have also thousands other errors, it doesn't mean you can omit required formatting.

Comment: @Col. I mean I've tried every suggestion, reference etc online that claims to be "correct!" and nothing is solving this issue. I must be doing something stupid here or my MySQL is corrupt!

Comment: @OldWest you should not "try" "every" suggestion. you should **LEARN** from the **documentation**. As for this one - it's absolutaly correct. and you should not "try" it. you should always use it! and then proceed to other errors

Comment: @OldWest. at a glance your query seems to produce this `INSERT INTO badges (..) VALUES (..) VALUES (..) VALUES (..)` and this is not valid sql. It seems you misplaced your `for loop` if I am reading it right

Comment: @Col why not stop bashing the OP and including me. If you are Mr. know-all then answer his question. so yeah i check the docs and here is what i found `INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)` close enough to the OP's query but not the same.

Comment: @Aivan better this time :) that's why I "bashing". It's always good to know that someone learned something useful :)

Answer (score 1):

your error was that you do not concatenate sql query properly and try to use single quotation around value that you are going to insert in database. it may also raise error.

enter code here`

```
<?
$db_name = "test";
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
$sql = "INSERT INTO badges        (company_name,company_address,company_city,company_state,company_zip, badge_name,   badge_title) VALUES ";

for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['badge_name']); $i++) 
{
  $sql .= "('". $_SESSION['company_name'] . "','"
            . $_SESSION['company_address'] . "','"
            . $_SESSION['company_city'] . "','"
            . $_SESSION['company_state'] . "','"
            . $_SESSION['company_zip'] . "','"
            . $_POST['badge_name'][$i] . "','"
            . $_POST['badge_title'][$i] ."')";

  if($i<count($_POST['badge_name'])-1){$sql .=',';} // if your array count is more than one than add , to make query compatible with mysql sytax  
}
echo $sql;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>`
```

Comment: Your -1 suggestion solved my final problem : ) I was trying things like that, but I could not get it right.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['badge_name']); $i++) 
{
$sql .= "('"
        . $_SESSION['company_name'] . "','"
        . $_SESSION['company_address'] . "','"
        . $_SESSION['company_city'] . "','"
        . $_SESSION['company_state'] . "','"
        . $_SESSION['company_zip'] . "','"
        . $_POST['badge_name'][$i] . "','"
        . $_POST['badge_title'][$i] ."')";

if($i<count($_POST['badge_name'])-1){$sql .=',';}  
}
```

Comment: you forgot mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score -1):

First off, since this is an insertion, we'll remove id, also, you are overwriting $sql in the for loop (`$sql =` instead of `$sql .=`) and the session keys are malformed and non-integer inputs should be quoted.  I assumed that zip is stored as an integer, if not add change it to `'$_SESSION['company_zip']'`:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO badges (company_name,company_address,company_city,company_state,company_zip,badge_name,badge_title) VALUES ";
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['badge_name']); $i++) 
{
     $sql .= "('$_SESSION['company_name']','$_SESSION['company_address']','$_SESSION['company_city']','$_SESSION['company_state']',$_SESSION['company_zip'],'$_POST['badge_name'][$i]','$_POST['badge_title'][$i]')";
}
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
echo print_r($sql);
?>
```

Comment: Still not working properly. Same mixed results : ( Sometimes the badge_name is cut to one character. Cannot get rid of the MySQL Insert error no matter what variation I try!

Comment: What's the structure of $_POST?

Comment: Care to run your code? just to see if there are some silly PHP syntax errors?